# JavaFX Stage To Front

Tags: javafx

JavaFX Stage supports the method toFront() to force the stage window to the front of other windows.

From what I've found this only tends to work when show() is first called, then followed by a toFront().

However, what do we do in the case of a call to Stage's showAndWait() since placing a call to toFront() directly after isn't going to do anything? I want to wait, but I also want my stage window to the front.

Comment: You could try `theStage.setOnShown(e -> theStage.toFront()); theStage.showAndWait();`.

Comment: Although these are different things and you may have already looked at them, please recheck the documentation for each, to see if one or some combination of these parameters is not a better solution for you:  [`initModality`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initModality(javafx.stage.Modality)), [`initOwner`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initOwner(javafx.stage.Window)) or [`alwaysOnTop`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)).

Comment: Also review the main [`Stage`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html) javadoc sections titled "Owner" and "Modality", which further explain the settings mentioned above.  I advise actually creating a small prototype app with multiple stages and different settings combinations that you can use to test the operation on your target platforms to determine some settings that allow operating as you wish.

Comment: Also review [`Dialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) implementations (and their subclasses) and see if they are also not better suited for your purpose (they may or may not be).  Dialog behavior: "JavaFX dialogs are modal by default (you can change this via the initModality(javafx.stage.Modality) API). To specify whether you want blocking or non-blocking dialogs, developers simply choose to call showAndWait() or show() (respectively). By default most developers should choose to use showAndWait(), given the ease of coding in these situations".

Comment: Slaw - Thanks a lot - that works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Stage constructor class to make the call to toFront in a Platform.RunLater block.